# Typescript: Type of exported AMD class not found

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd

Im using Typescript with a requirejs setup, so typescript is configured to use AMD modules.

I'm trying to export a class and use it from another one. Here is some example code.

```ts
//file: ClassA.ts
export = class ClassA {
}

//file: ClassB.ts
import ClassA = require("ClassA")

export = class ClassB {
    constructor(classA: ClassA) { //ClassA is not found
        // However this will work:
        let c = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

When compiling I get the following error.

> ClassB.ts(4,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ClassA'.

However intellisense is fine with the instanciation of ClassA and I get full intellisense for the instance.

So what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing JavaScript and TypeScript syntax for exporting and importing classes.
Try this syntax:

```
ClassA.ts:
export class ClassA {
    print() {
        console.log(`ClassA.print()`);
    }
}

ClassB.ts:
import {ClassA} from './ClassA';

class ClassB {
    print() {
        let a = new ClassA();
        a.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! I didn't know you could use es6 module syntax with AMD modules.

Comment: The module syntax that TypeScript uses is based on es6.  The compiler will take care of generating either AMD or commonJs syntax based on the setting in tsconfig.json.